# Hyperlink in jquery booklet plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying jquery booklet plugin (http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/). This i working perfectly but i am not able to put any hyperlink inside the book content. Please help me to create hyperlink (a href) on images in text inside booklet page.

Thanks a lot. I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
overlays: false
```

option when initializes this plugin. This parameter set to true by default and enables navigation using a page sized overlay. When enabled links inside the content will not be clickable.

Comment: Thanks its working but now i am not able to move on next page :(

Comment: Try arrows: true option (false by default) or next, prev options (for setting external elements to move by pages) or use menu and pageSelector for enabling navigation with a dropdown menu of pages.

Comment: you can set manual and hover to true, so you can drag the page on the edge to turn. However, does anybody know if I can do manual page turn on ios4?

Comment: @CoolEsh i want that second page should show page numbers for all other pages ? as i use overlays:false it disable the next and previous events on page click ?\

Comment: i solved my purpose by adjusting the resetpage() method using this     if (opts.curr == 2) {
                    //alert('z-index 100');
                    b.find('.b-page-' + (2)).css('z-index', '100');
                    b.find('.b-page-' + (3)).css('z-index', '100');
                }
                else {
                    //alert('z-index 10');
                    b.find('.b-page-' + (2)).css('z-index', '10');
                    b.find('.b-page-' + (3)).css('z-index', '10');
                }